# How do you Synthesise Glycosides of flavonoids and stilbenoids?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I would like to know how you go about synthesising glycosides of flavonoids and stilbenoids from their respective sugars and flavonoids/stilbenoids. I read http://www.netsci-journal.com/97v1/97005/005p20.htm but I found it too specific (as it only applied to aliphatic compounds) and required an enzymatic catalyst that is impossible to predict. I would like a general formula that if it does contain an enzymatic catalyst the enzyme is either constant or at least usually predictable.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by a 'constant or usually predictable enzyme'?

Comment: An enzyme that doesn't change (i.e. is constant) or is predictable by some mathematical model.

Comment: My educated guess would be that such an enzyme does not exist. Enzymes are usually very specific to their substrates. As for predictability, it is possible to model an enzyme to a desired substrate using computational methods (i.e. Molecular Modelling). However you might be better off looking into classical organic synthesis methods, retrosynthesis specifically.

Comment: In terms of process, sugars tend to be exceedingly insoluble in organic media.  Simple per-acetylation of glucose is not a high yield reaction. If the glucose is ball-milled overnight (lapidary tumbler no more than 1/3 full including grinding balls), the micronized glucose reacts in very good yield.  There are other tricks to helping things move along one you have the synthesis itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to forget about the enzymes.

**Pepare for a probably lengthy synthesis - you will need patience and a clever protection/deprotection scheme.**

The following is definitely not applicable to all starting materials but might give some directions.

[image: quercetin numbering and acetal formation]

If the flavonoid contains a catechol moiety, just like *quercetin* (**1**), the vicinal phenolic $\ce{OH}$ groups can be protected as an acetal by heating the starting material with $\alpha,\alpha$-dichlordiphenylmethane in diphenylether ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.3762/bjoc.5.60)). The protecting groups is easily removed by hydrogenation over $\ce{Pd/C}$ at 1 atm.

Note that the PMB (4-methoxybenzyl) group is another protecting group for (phenolic) $\ce{OH}$ that gets off by hydrogenation.

As far as selectivities for the protection of the other $\ce{OH}$ groups in **1** are concerned, have a look at the 1962 paper by [Leonard Jurd](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jo01051a041), who described that **the methylation of quercetine pentaacetate in dry acetone predominantly furnishes 7-*O*-methylquercetin**. There are quite some more recent articles citing this!